# QImage::setPixel: coordinate out of range

Tags: c++, qt, image-processing, bmp

i am beginner in QT

i try to open binary file and draw it pixel by pixel

i got this warning when i was debugging

```
QImage::setPixel: coordinate (67,303) out of range
QImage::setPixel: coordinate (67,306) out of range
QImage::setPixel: coordinate (67,309) out of range
QImage::setPixel: coordinate (67,312) out of range
```

and this is the code

```
    unsigned char* data = new unsigned char[row_padded];
    unsigned char tmp;
    QImage myImage;
    myImage = QImage(width, height, QImage::Format_RGB888);

    for(int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        fread(data, sizeof(unsigned char), row_padded, file);
        for(int j = 0; j < width*3; j += 3)
        {
            // Convert (B, G, R) to (R, G, B)
            tmp = data[j];
            data[j] = data[j+2];
            data[j+2] = tmp;

                    myImage.setPixel((width*3)-j, height-i, RGB((int)data[j],(int)data[j+1],(int)data[j+2]));
        }
    }
```

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You incorrectly calculate x and y coordinate on this line:

```
myImage.setPixel((width*3)-j, height-i, RGB((int)data[j],(int)data[j+1],(int)data[j+2]));
```

x should be instead:

```
 width - j / 3 - 1
```

y should be

```
 height - i - 1
```

or maybe it is better to use another variable for x to avoid division:

```
for(int i = 0; i < height; i++)
{
    fread(data, sizeof(unsigned char), row_padded, file);
    int x = width;
    for(int j = 0; j < width*3; j += 3)
    {
        // Convert (B, G, R) to (R, G, B)
        tmp = data[j];
        data[j] = data[j+2];
        data[j+2] = tmp;

        myImage.setPixel(--x, height-i-1, RGB((int)data[j],(int)data[j+1],(int)data[j+2]));
    }
}
```

Suggestions: it is better to define variable right before it is used:

```
unsigned char tmp = data[j];
data[j] = data[j+2];
data[j+2] = tmp;
```

or even better

```
std::swap( data[j], data[j+2] );
```

Comment: still out of range :(